# I installed airflow using microk8s helm, but access to localhost:8080 is denied

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, microk8s

I am just getting started with Kubernetes. I'm using microk8s and I'm currently having a mental breakdown. My 5 days are being spent here.

I currently have airflow installed using microk8s helm. However, I forwarded to port 8080, but the connection is being refused.And i'm using AWS EC2

### helm chart

[https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/tree/main/charts/airflow](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

### pod status

[image]

### webserver log

[image]
[image]

### Describe

[image]

### Port

I allowed port 8080 in security group of aws ec2

### Port-forward 8080

i did `kubectl port-forward svc/airflow-web 8080:8080`
[image]

### and check port

i did `netstat -ntlp`
[image]

### and

i did `kubectl get cs`
[image]

...but I connected to 127.0.0.1:8080 but the connection was denied:

[image]

Here is the log for postgresql. There is an error, is it related to this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  service:
type: NodePort
externalPort: 8080
```

I solved the problem by changing the webserver's service type to NodePort.

In the case of ClusterIP, I don't know why I can't connect

In the instance security group, I allowed all ports 30000 - 32767

i am very happy